# Autoregistration with Unity and Prism not working

Tags: unity-container, prism-5

I'm having this configuration with Unity and Prism:

```
public class EmployeeDataService : IEmployeeDataService
{
}
public class EmployeeController(IEmployeeDataService dataService)
{
    this.dataService = dataService;
}

public class EmployeeModuleInit : IModule
{
   readonly IUnityContainer container;
   readonly IRegionManager  regionManager;
   readonly EmployeeController employeeController;

   public EmployeeModuleInit(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager, EmployeeController employeeController)
   {
       this.container     = container;
       this.regionManager = regionManager;
       this.employeeController = employeeController;
   }
}
```

The types are mapped using:

```
Container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.TypeName,
    WithLifetime.Transient );
```

Yet, at start-up I'm getting this error:

**{"The current type, IEmployeeDataService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?"}**

IUnityContainer and IRegionManager are properly registered and resolved, however they are registered manually in the Prism.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.cs and I don't want to manually register all types in the project.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

That registration by convention is registering all types with a name.  I think you probably wanted this instead...

```
Container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.Transient);
```

Comment: This is partially correct. The container is able to discover and register the types using the above configuration **only** if the interfaces and implementing types are in the same assembly. In my case, some interfaces are in a different assembly and the registration still fails.

Comment: It's possible the interface assembly haven't been "loaded" yet.  `AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()` will only pull from assemblies that have been loaded by the runtime.  Just for debugging purposes, try to call `Assembly.Load("InterfaceAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0")` before the call to Unity to see if that is the issue.

Comment: Ok, ref. `FromLoadedAssemblies()`, I thought as much. But I changed that to `AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath()` and loaded only assemblies specific to my project. And it's the same error.
Then I explictly loaded the assembly containing the interfaces and again the same error.

Comment: Are you certain your assembly where the concrete types live is getting copied to the bin directory of the application?  With that level of loose coupling, you may no longer be needing to reference the concrete assembly, so it is not getting automatically copied to bin.